# Emacs: check if filepath contains directory name

Tags: python, emacs, elisp

I try to write code in emacs. I have many different python projects, all of them have space indentation, except one. I want to check if open file path contains directory name of this project and set tabs instead of spaces, only for files in this directory.

I try

```
(when (string-match "project_name" buffer-file-name)
     do sth)
```

But it wasn`t work

Also, if you write how to set tabs for python and javascript files it will helps a lot)

**UPD**

My work code

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
  (lambda()
   (setq tab-width 4)
   (setq python-indent 4)
   (if (string-match-p "project_name" (or (buffer-file-name) ""))
       (setq indent-tabs-mode t)
     (setq indent-tabs-mode nil))))
```

Comment: And the indentation guessing does not work? Tabs are really not recommended btw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple answer

```
 (when (string-prefix-p "/home/user/project-path" (buffer-file-name))
   ;;do sth
   )
```

You may also need to use `expand-file-name` to get a full path to match `buffer-file-name` so that you can handle something like `"~/project-paht"`.

```
(expand-file-name (buffer-file-name))
```

You may also need to take care `nil` result from `buffer-file-name` by

```
(or (buffer-file-name) "")
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do for the check is:

```
(when (string-match-p "project_name" (buffer-file-name))
      (message "cat"))
```

`buffer-file-name` is a function and `string-match-p` returns true or false regarding a string match